# how to retrieve all surveys in my site using javascript/csom

Tags: 2013, javascript, csom, survey

I have created some surveys using survey app,I want to list all surveys existing on my site using client object model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link to get the detauils from survey list,
http://swatipoint.blogspot.in/2011/12/sharepoint-client-object-modellist.html

Comment: I want to display all surveys what ever i created in site using survey app

Comment: Retrieve  the items from survey app.http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/caml-query-to-retrieve-the-items-from-a-list-using-csom1

Comment: @GowthamRajamanickam pls dont post only link .Add answer with content and refer the link.Link may go down any time making this useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [http://sitecollection/site/_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseType eq 4](http://sitecollection/site/_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseType%20eq%204) to list the surveys for your website (the lists with [BaseType=4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx) represent the surveys).